# how can i appendChild without deleting the referenced child

Tags: php, dom

Here's a sample of my xml. Let's say:

```
<Elements>
    <Element>
        <list>123</list>
    </Element>

    <Element>
        <list>456</list>
    </Element>
</Elements>
```

i have a function that gets the element->item(0);
then i append it to the element->item(1);
and my appending code is like this:

```
$elements=$xml->getElementsBytagName('Element');
$element1=$elements->item(0);
$element2=$elements->item(1);
$element2->appenchild($element1);
```

but content of element 1 is deleted. but added to the element2.

is there a way that the content of element 1 stays there and adds it to element 2? i tried appending it to the element 1 too but it's not really the way how my code must go. please help. :( thanks

Comment: Could you post the code you are using? You could probably just call cloneNode on the appended element to make a copy of it like: `element->item(0)->cloneNode(true);`

Comment: can i use element->item(0)->cloneNode(element1); ??

Comment: The value passed into cloneNode is just a boolean value of whether to include child nodes in the clone. Without code I was just guessing as to which element you wanted to clone but you use it like `elementYouWantToClone->cloneNode(true);`. So you want to clone `element->item(1)` then you would call `element->item(1)->cloneNode(true)`. Or if `element1` was a DOMNode, `element1->cloneNode(true)`. http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.clonenode.php

Comment: i've edited the content. thank you. i'm trying to use cloneNode now.

Comment: So your last line would be `$element2->appenchild($element1->cloneNode(true));`. However, that will copy the actual `$element1` under `$element2`. If you want just the `list` node you would need to go through childNodes and add each one or do the same `getElementsByTagName` looking for the `list` element and append each one.

Comment: can i pass the elementYouWantToClone->cloneNode(true); to a variable so i can append it to the element2? or am i in a wrong way i'm really confused.

Comment: cloneNode just creates a copy of an element (node). You could save it to a variable and append the variable. Same thing.

Comment: thanks its clear now. God Bless :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cloneNode is the way to go.  Example:

```
element[1].appendChild(element[0].childNodes[0].cloneNode(true));
```

The above will take the first child of the first item in the element nodeList and append it as a child to the second item in the element nodeList without removing it from the original location.

Comment: This example is javascript. The question notes PHP and apparently is using the php DOMDocument classes.